# Content Deployment of a Single Site Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, content-deployment

I'm trying to deploy Content of a "Single" subsite from ServerA to ServerB/SiteCollectionA.

When I select "Specific sites within the site collection" within Scope of a new Job and run / test it. It always add Root Site "/" as well to the Scope list. Hence it tries to deploy the root site and the specified subsite.

**I do not want to deploy the Root site.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the out-of-the-box Content Deployment features of SharePoint there is no way around this.  The Site Collection requires the RootWeb to go with it.  Your other option could be to create a new Site Collection at a managed path (like /sites/mynewsite, or /newmanagedpath) and move your content to the RootWeb of that site collection.  Here is some information on Managed Paths: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845.aspx (applies to both 2010 and 2013).

Comment: Thanks John. I'll moved all the bulky stuff (photos & videos) from the Root site to a subsite. So that it will be small enough to copy.